# Can't Increase Java Heap Space Google Colab

Tags: java, google-colaboratory

I am running a scala program in Google Colab, however I am running into the `java.lang.outofmemoryerror: java heap space` error.

What I have tried, is to go into `$ sudo vim /etc/profile` and increase it by:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx8192m
```

I tried running this too `!export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms8192m -Xmx8192m"`

However when running `$ java -XshowSettings:vm` to check, it shows:

```
VM settings:
Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 3.17G
Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
```

How else can I overcome this issue, as my program breaks when it reaches the error.

Comment: How are you starting the scala program? Also, are you running colab in the cloud and trying to reconfigure the the heap in that terminal?

Comment: I am running the scala program through the Joern terminal with the `cpg.runScript` command. Yes I am running it in the cloud, and reconfiguring the heap in that terminal